# how can I set the StartBounds, units, and tileSize correctly in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, cartography

how can I set the StartBounds, units, and tileSize correctly in OpenLaters?I can not make sure this parameters,for I use jsonp,and it will dynamticly read layerinfo from esri rest resources.

```
 var maxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(102.9702000357959, 26.573810737410064, 110.21822155809812, 29.11729567697843);
    baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache("baseMap", layerURL, {
        isBaseLayer: true,
        //numZoomLevels: 11,
        StartBounds: maxExtent,
        zoom: 5,
        layerInfo: layerInfo,
        projection: 'EPSG:' + layerInfo.spatialReference.wkt
    });
    console.log(layerInfo.spatialReference.wkt);
    //console.log(baseLayer.spatialReference);
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        StartBounds: maxExtent,
        initialExtent: baseLayer.initialExtent,
        maxExtent: maxExtent,
        units: (baseLayer.units == "esriFeet") ? 'ft' : 'm',
        resolutions: baseLayer.resolutions,
        tileSize: baseLayer.tileSize,
        eventListeners: { //set event handler
            "moveend": moveEvent},
        //displayProjection: baseLayer.displayProjection
        projection: 'EPSG:' + layerInfo.spatialReference.wkt
    });
```